# Add metaresource between label

Tags: html, asp.net

```
<label id="lblForUdlandAdr1" runat="server"><% meta:resourcekey="lblPamindelseResource1" %></label>
```

I need to add a local resource between label start and closing tags. But above code is not working

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try with `<asp:Localize>`

```
<asp:Localize runat="server" ID="Name" Text="Name:" meta:resourcekey="lblPamindelseResource1" />
```